# Is there anywhere I can store and access easily with python a text file online?

Tags: python, file, text, cloud, storage

I am writing a program in python and, although the file handling is great on local storage, I was wondering if there was any way to store a variable, or a text file on the internet and easily read and write from it as if I were handling files in python?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You just need one of two things: either a cloud provider that offers some kind of storage that your OS can turn into networked file sharing, or a Python module that wraps up some kind of cloud storage in file-like objects.

For the first one, to give a silly but doable example, you could create a Amazon Web Storage instance, configure a CIFS (`smbd`) or NFS (`nfsd`) server on it, set up the firewall settings so you can access it, then just mount the store. Alternatively, you could just serve the files up over HTTP (or WebDAV) or FTP or even IMAP (email), and configure your local OS to treat the service as a virtual filesystem (e.g., one of the samples for FUSE lets you mount an FTP server as a local filesystem).

However, the second one is usually a better option. Most things in Python don't actually care whether they get a real file, they just want a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), something that provides the same API as a real file object. In Python 3.x, there are explicit interfaces for this API in the `io` module (see the links in the glossary entry); in Python 2.x, it's a bit more vague and implicit (although in 2.7, you can still use the `io` module ABCs for your implementation). You can write anything you want, or you can search around PyPI for things people have already written. For example, [`ftputil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/3.1) can create file-like objects (and even fake local directories with the same interface as the `os` module) out of an FTP server.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to send and receive data to the Internet. Then, some web app may store and give you the data. I doubt using open() to save/receive files on the Internet is possible without Linux trickery (symlinks or writing to a Linux /device)

Comment: What does `requests` add here? It doesn't solve his problem, and it doesn't get him any closer to a solution that `urllib` or `ftplib` or a hundred other things he could build on that are already in the stdlib.